# A word for someone who backs out of a sale

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a good word for someone who backs out of a purchase? I'm thinking maybe reneger but I don't think that's a smart financial term.

Comment: Are you looking for a positive, negative or neutral term? Is the backing out motivated by another party's actions, or their own? In the context you have in mind, is backing out considered to be a normal and anticipated action (e.g. look at a car - no damage, agree to buy it; on delivery, the car is damaged)? Also, please [edit] your question to add a sample sentence.

Comment: a tease, perhaps?

Comment: Need more information  A person could back out of a purchase for many reasons, ranging from buyer's remorse to knavery. The word one would use to describe such a person would depend on the reason.

Comment: Your title says sale but your question says purchase.  The question is unclear.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend **[welch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/welch)**.

> welch (n) A person who defaults on an obligation, especially a small one.

Also the verb *to welch* and an alternative noun *welcher*.

Comment: Note also that this term is currently going out of style because of its racist overtones ([referring to the Welsh](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=welch))

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem you're running into is one of connotation rather than of denotation, I might suggest a more obscure word.  Runagate or tergiversator would denote the same thing as reneger or welcher without the very negative connotations.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use "withdrawer"? This would have a neutral connotation.

However, I'm not sure it's a real word.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/withdrawer seems legit.